# Logic issue spawning a set number of game objects when game object is destroyed if collides with something?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a dilemma with a basic game in Unity with C# - I need to spawn 10 cubes in random locations, however once a cube is spawned I destroy it if it detects a collision with another game object in this script ATTACHED to the cube object:

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision col){

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Maze" || col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {

            //Destroy cube
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            spawnCubes.numCubesExist--;

            Debug.Log ("touching!!" + spawnCubes.numCubesExist);

            spawnCubes.touchedMaze = true;

        }
    }
```

In another script in my scene I spawn the cubes here. I am using public static int `numCubesExist` to enumerate the number of cubes in the scene (although this doesn't work) and `NUMTOBESPAWNED` to set the number of cubes that SHOULD end up in the scene.

In the cube script, `numCubesExist` is decreased by 1 if collision is detected and when a cube is spawned by `cubeSpawner ();` I increment. My logic is that my while statement would keep spawning UNTIL `numCubesExist == NUMTOBESPAWNED` but this does not happen.

```
void Start () {

        while(numCubesExist <= NUMTOBESPAWNED)
        {
            cubeSpawner ();
        }

    }
void cubeSpawner()
    {
        //Random textures
        switch (Random.Range (0, 3)) {
        case 0:
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = color1;

            break;

        case 1:
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = color2;

            break;

        case 2:
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = color3;
            break;

        case 3:
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = color4;

            break;

        }

        //Random positions
        if (UIManagerScript.sceneNum == 0) {
            position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (7.0F, 26.0F), (float)1.4, Random.Range (-9.0F, 10.0F));
            Debug.Log (position);
        }
        else if(UIManagerScript.sceneNum == 1) {
            position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (7.0F, 47.0F), (float)1.4, Random.Range (-9.0F, 10.0F));
            Debug.Log (position);
        }
        else if(UIManagerScript.sceneNum == 2) {
            position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-4.7F, 44.0F), (float)1.4, Random.Range (-23.0F, 25.0F));
            Debug.Log (position);
        }

        //spawn
        Instantiate (cube, position, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log ("spawned it!"+numCubesExist);
        numCubesExist++;
    }
```

My Debug.Log statements within the collision on the cube script are printed AFTER all the spawn statements are printed, so what I'm seeing is the cubes spawn the correct number, then half of them are destroyed and NOT REPLACED by the `OnCollisionStay`. So I'm always left with less cubes than `NUMTOBESPAWNED`.

I'm new to Unity- what is the best way to achieve this? Where should I call my while loop (In update just results in a million cubes)?

EDIT to enumerate cubes:

```
GameObject[] allObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("blueCube");
        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects) {
            cubesInScene++;
        }
```

Comment: Let me get this straight. The cube is spawned and destroyed in OnCollisionStay but you want the number of cubes in the scene to be NUMTOBESPAWNED amount at-all time?

Comment: No - just initially. When I start the scene I want there to be  NUMTOBESPAWNED cubes after all the spawning and destroying is done. (The only reason I destroy on collision is because otherwise I get cubes spawning within walls)

Comment: You might be having a racing condition. Say you wanted 5 cubes. Your while loop spawns all 5 of them meaning that the number of cubes matches the expected. The while loop ends and then one of the cubes detects its colliding with something and removes it self. At that point the number of cubes is 4, but the while loop already ended.

Comment: Just to clarify what you basically already noticed: `Start()` is always called before the first `OnCollisionStay()`. You can see the whole ordering of events here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: @NickOtten yes- what would you suggest as a way around the problem?

Comment: Big disclaimer: I'm not a game developer, I only hobby with Unity once in a while so I don't know if this is the 'nicest' solution. But personally I would check the spot I want to place a cube. in other words: I'd pick a random coordinate with the random generator (within the bounds of the scene). I would take that point as the center point of the cube. Then check if the required space is not over a wall or other cube. If its free spawn the cube. If not then either move it to where it is all free. Or be lazy with your implementation and roll for a new coordinate (Inefficient!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I see, I hope this helps!

1. Your spawner does not guarantee the cube is not spawning right next (or into) a "Maze" or "Player" object, so most probably it happens every now and then and your cubes get destroyed right after they spawned. As "Nick Otten" highlights, your spawn-loop is already over when this happens so no new cubes are spawned in place of the destroyed ones.
   To solve this, you can do several things. Here's a few examples:

   - Create spawner GOs in the Scene and guarantee both "Maze" and "Player" are outside of it's pre-defined range (let's say a 10 units globe), as well as the cubes are guaranteed spawned inside; you can make it simple -as of coding- and add a collider to your spawners' "globe", and with [IgnoreLayerCollision](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html) make unwanted items to repel ("stay outside") and others to fall through ("stay inside"). E.g. cubes repel and player(s) stay inside or vice versa.
   - You can apply a different collision mechanism in "spawning phase". I.e. on [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html), you make the objects repel / bounce-off / etc each other, instead of cubes getting destroyed. As soon as spawning phase is over, it is guaranteed nothing is touching and you can switch to "destroy mechanism" / "play mode"
   - Slow and an overhead so I don't recommend it, but you can keep spawning and spawning until all cubes stay (i.e. none gets destroyed after it was spawned)
2. Instead of "numCubesExist" and such, why don't you create a cube prefab queue (and hide/requeue them in script instead of destroy)? Here's a nice tutorial on how to do this: [Object Pooling Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhqP3EghQ-Q) (*I also recommend Sebastian's other tutorials, he is doing a great job in teaching Unity*)
3. In your cube spawner method, instead of a switch, why don't you do something like this?

   ```
   //class variable
   private Material[] colorMats; //fill up in Start() with color mats.
   //then in cubeSpawner:
   cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = colorMats[Random.Range(0, colorMats.Length)];
   ```

   So whenever you make change to your materials (e.g. add a new one), you have to alter your initialization code only, at one place, in Start()

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my problem. When the player starts to move (the game has officially started) I need there to be NUMTOBESPAWNED (ex: 7)  cubes to be 1. in the scene 2. not moving. By not destroying them and letting them bounce off, they bounce up into the air and keep moving. If I turn off the colliders they spawn within the walls. I cannot use your sphere technique as I am spawning my cubes within a maze (walls are everywhere)

Comment: Is there a way to just enumerate the number of cubes in the scene after all the destroying is done and then spawn the number that has been destroyed? There has to be a way around this..

Comment: @skyguy Yes, there is. That was the "not recommended" branch. Most simple one you could use is "FindObjectOfType" (or "FindObjectsOfType"). Also, if it's a mase and it's baked you could create a NavMesh and spawn things inside, i.e. at places where the cubes are in place: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html

Comment: Ok I have no succeeded in enumerating number in cubes in scene after spawn but if I just call spawn again the number of times that is needed for the number of cubes in scene to reach the correct number odds are I will need to do this repeatedly as some cubes will be destroyed from colliding with a wall. And if I do this in update I'm going to get errors. What would you suggest? I have updated code

Comment: @skyguy I suggest what I described in my answer. The way you do this is not right. You'll get one error after the other along with serious performance and stability issues. You'll have to refactor your code and do things right. As another hack or workaround, which I also do NOT recommend, you can place loads of empty GameObjects on your map, and spawn your cubes onto some of those so you can be sure those are placed at the right spot. E.g. place 30 GOs and you'll spawn just 10 cubes (select randomly which 10 GOs), it will look somewhat random to the player.